# NLog - How to prevent site from crashing when database throws error

Tags: sql-server, nlog

We currently use NLog in our website to log messages into an MSSQL database, instead of a regular log file.

How can we configure NLog to ignore any database errors instead of crashing the website when the database cannot be found?

Comment: Personally i would start at the root and figure out why the database cannot be found at times?

Comment: Maybe you need to configure NLog output?, if you haven't a database you should configure to write to file or turn off log. Otherwise try and catch is the common way to manage errors

Comment: maybe I don't really understand your question, but seems wrapping your logger with try-catch will do?

Comment: @MeanGreen Can you show the entire callstack for the Exception ? (`ex.ToString`). Have you checked the internal log https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging ? NLog should not throw exceptions by default, unless you have wrongfully activated `throwExceptions`

Answer (score -1):

Using a Try, Catch clause is used often with catching Database Exceptions from **Invalid Operations to Connectivity issues**. NLog seems to handle exception logging pretty efficiently and I would Log these at **Error Level**. The following is my production code(not exactly) and it seems to handle both object level errors and database errors.

```
try
{
//Database Operations...
}
catch (SqlException sqlException)
{    
logger.Error(sqlException, "Sql exception caught while Importing.");
}
catch (NullReferenceException nullRefException)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        DBConnTxn.ConnectDB();
                        DBConnTxn.ExecuteUpdateQuery("ROLLBACK TRAN");
                        DBConnTxn.DisconnectDB();
                        logger.Error(nullRefException, "Null Reference exception caught while Importing.");
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        logger.Error(ex, "DB Roll Back Exception while importing.");
                        return false;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                catch (ArgumentException argsException)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        DBConnTxn.ConnectDB();
                        DBConnTxn.ExecuteUpdateQuery("ROLLBACK TRAN");
                        DBConnTxn.DisconnectDB();
                    }
                    catch { }
                    logger.Error(argsException, "Null Reference exception caught while Importing.");
                    FullAutoMailSendHelper.ProcessErrors.Add("Data Import Error", argsException.Message);
                    return false;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        logger.Fatal(ex, "Unhandled Exception occurred");
                        DBConnTxn.ConnectDB();
                        DBConnTxn.ExecuteUpdateQuery("ROLLBACK TRAN");
                        DBConnTxn.DisconnectDB();
                    }
                    catch(Exception innerException) {
                    }

                    FullAutoMailSendHelper.ProcessErrors.Add("Data Import Error",ex.Message);
                    return false;
                }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think you misunderstand the question. When Nlog is trying to log to the database but it ends in an exception I don't want the entire application to crash but to ignore the Nlog error and continue.

Comment: In that case, you would either turn off all NLog internal exceptions or better still make your very own Custom Target. It is very easy to extend NLog. But either way you still will have to Try and Catch even if you're extending it.

Comment: If you don't like my answer, I can remove it.